# Select 3 Distinct columns return 5 columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, primary-key

```
SELECT DoctorId, Plan, StartDate, EndDate,Status
From DoctorContracts
```

In `DoctorContracts` Table  I need `Distinct doctorid`, `plan` and `StartDate` but I need to get `Status` and `Enddate`

However There is a Group column which is either CA or NH. I need the minimum StartDate between CA or NH.

Example

```
DOCTORID.        PLAN.      STARTDATE.          ENDATE.          STATUS.     GROUP
9978.            Abc.       11/2/2010.          11/2/2015.       Z.          CA 
9978.            Abc.       11/2/2013.          11/2/2015.       N.          NH  
9978.            Xxx.       12/3/2011.          12/3/2015.       Z.          CA
9978.            Xxx.       10/3/2001.          12/6/2015.       Z.          NH
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, I will post my code tomorrow. Thanks again. I have tried several ways. The issue is we are moving from a table with 8 columns as pkey to a table with 3 pkeys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the `ROW_NUMBER` function https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx:

Here is what your SQL should look like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT d.[DoctorId]
      , d.[Plan]
      , d.[StartDate]
      , d.[EndDate]
      , d.[Status]
FROM DoctorContracts as d
    INNER JOIN 
        (SELECT [GROUP]
              , [STARTDATE]
              , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [GROUP] ORDER BY [STARTDATE] ASC) AS Row
         FROM DoctorContracts) as t
    ON d.[GROUP] = t.[GROUP]
        AND d.[STARTDATE] = t.[STARTDATE]
        AND t.[Row] = 1
```

You create a subset based on the min date partitioned by the group, and then filter to the earliest date.

I have tested in SSMS, and it works as requested.